# ggplot reordering w/ interaction

Tags: r, interaction, geom-bar

I have the following table.   I need to order the data by `Freq` , however, I also need to show two x-axis labels - one for `start.station` and one for `end.station` so that it is clear that I am talking about station pairs.  I used `interaction` but now am not sure how to input the code to order by `Freq` as well.  Also, I would like to show the start.station on the top X-axis and the end.station on the bottom X - axis.

```
> new_pairs
 x    y Freq start.latittude start.longitude              start.station
1  359  519  929        40.75188       -73.97770         Pershing\nSquare N
2  477  465 5032        40.75514       -73.98658        Broadway &\nW 41 St
3  484  519 1246        40.75188       -73.97770         Pershing\nSquare N
4  484  318 2654        40.75320       -73.97799 E 43 St &\nVanderbilt\nAve
5  492  267 1828        40.75098       -73.98765        Broadway &\nW 36 St
6  492  498  957        40.74855       -73.98808        Broadway &\nW 32 St
7  492  362 1405        40.75173       -73.98754        Broadway &\nW 37 St
8  493  477 1582        40.75641       -73.99003           W 41 St &\n8 Ave
9  493  529  728        40.75757       -73.99099           W 42 St &\n8 Ave
10 529 2021 1748        40.75929       -73.98860           W 45 St &\n8 Ave
   end.latitude end.longitude        end.station
1      40.75510     -73.97499 E 47 St &\nPark Av
2      40.75641     -73.99003   W 41 St &\n8 Ave
3      40.75500     -73.98014   W 44 St &\n5 Ave
4      40.75500     -73.98014   W 44 St &\n5 Ave
5      40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
6      40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
7      40.75020     -73.99093   W 33 St &\n7 Ave
8      40.75680     -73.98291   W 45 St &\n6 Ave
9      40.75680     -73.98291   W 45 St &\n6 Ave
10     40.75757     -73.99099   W 42 St &\n8 Ave    


ggplot(data= new_pairs, aes(x= interaction(end.station,start.station)    y=Freq)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  ylab("Bikes received") + 
  xlab("Station")
```

[image]

Comment: you could create your interaction prior to your plot and order your factor level like you want

Comment: how to make two separate x - axis on either end?

Comment: I don't think having 2 x axis is currently possible. Some have found a work around for 2 y axis, so maybe someone will come up with a solution

Comment: It's not a separate axis, its a separate set of labels - one should be on the stop, and the other on the bottom

Comment: see my answer below, was it what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using iris dataset. I create an interaction and use \n to have two sets of labels. You just need to adapt scale_x_discrete() expression for your dataset and it should work.

```
iris$Species2 <- iris$Species
iris$Int <- interaction(iris$Species2, iris$Species)

ggplot(data= iris, aes(x= Int, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_x_discrete("Int", labels = c("setosa.setosa" = "setosa\nsetosa","versicolor.versicolor" = "versicolor\nversicolor",
  "virginica.virginica" = "virginica\nvirginica"))
```

[image]

Comment: Aesthetically, remove the space after the \n (e.g. `"virginica.virginica" = "virginica \nvirginica"`)the two lines line up better.

Comment: @George, yah, I noticed it after posting, but thanks for commenting